# how to find JAR: /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar

Tags: java, python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I'm practicing a video tutorial from plural sight about Amazon EMR. I am stuck as i cannot proceed as i am getting this error

`Not a valid JAR: /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar`

Please note that tutorial is old and it is using a older Emr version. I am using the latest version is that a problem ?

The steps that i took are after entering the credentials in putty

> 1) Hadoop
>
> 2) mkdir streamingCode`
>
> 3) wget -o ./streamingCode/wordSplitter.py
>   s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py
>
> 4) hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar  -files
>   streamingCode/wordSplitter.py -mapper wordSplitter.py input
>   s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input -output
>   streamingCode/wordCountOut -reducer aggregate`

I cannot execute step 4 as i am getting the below error

`Not a valid JAR: /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar`

Comment: Solved By using previous version Amazon 2.4.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Hadoop streaming jar is still available in the latest release of EMR Hadoop.  Starting with EMR release 4.0.0 it can be found at `/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar`.

Another good resource for differences between versions can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-differences.html.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.  You answer helped me with the actual command needed here:  "hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files streamingCode/wordSplitter.py -mapper wordSplitter.py -input s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input -output streamingCode/wordCountOut -reducer aggregate"

Comment: Amazon should really update their documentation to reflect this change: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-launch-emr-jobflow-cli.html this tutorial is still using the old path and their log statements don't give you the slightest clue as to why things failed.

Answer (score 9):

For the variable, HADOOP_STREAMING, obtaining the path is a bit more complicated depending on the HDP you are using.

Search for where it is located via command:
find / -name 'hadoop-streaming*.jar'

*Src: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/installing-r-studio-server-on-hortonworks-virtual-box-image-and-rmr2-a-k-a-rhadoop-r-package/*